# g++ compile options with -std=c++14 compile error showing Werror=c++11-compat

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, c++14

My environment Arch Linux, gcc 7.2

I'm learning C++ and I'm using keyword `constexpr` to define a constant, while compile, it give me an error message
error: `identifier ‘constexpr’ is a keyword in C++11 [-Werror=c++11-compat]`

I can compile my program with default g++, but cannot compile with -std=c++14 and -Werror

The command I'm using is:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -ansi -flto
```

I believe the `-Werror` option caused the issue. but what is the issue? can someone tell me please?

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    constexpr double yen_dollar = 0.107;
    std::cout << yen_dollar << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

> ```
> test.cpp:4:5: error: identifier ‘constexpr’ is a keyword in C++11 [-Werror=c++11-compat]
>      constexpr double yen_dollar = 0.107;
>      ^~~~~~~~~
> test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
> test.cpp:4:5: error: ‘constexpr’ was not declared in this scope
> test.cpp:5:16: error: ‘yen_dollar’ was not declared in this scope
>      std::cout << yen_dollar << std::endl;
> ```

Comment: Weird. [This online version of GCC 7.2](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fab224d3405c3c0f) is compiling it without a hitch. Can you provide more details? Like the exact command line arguments?

Comment: Can you show the *exact* command line you use to build the source? Copy it (as text) and paste it into the body of the question without any modifications.

Comment: g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -ansi -flto Thanks

Comment: Get rid of then `-ansi` flag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the GCC documentation [§3.4 Options Controlling C Dialect](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options), one can read:

> ```
> -ansi
>
>   In C mode, this is equivalent to -std=c90. In C++ mode, it is equivalent to -std=c++98.
> ```

Since, you compiled with

```
g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -ansi -flto
```

`-ansi` overwrites `-std=c++14` with `-std=c++98`. This is why `constexpr` is not recognized.

**Solution**: get rid of the `-ansi` flag.